# How to read from a file and store it in a list of object (python)

Tags: python

This is my csv file

```
Dude, 1/1/2011, Brown, Jack Russell
Oogie, 1/1/2006, Grey, Fluffy
Big Bird, 10/11/1969, Yellow, Canary
Garfield, 1/1/1978, Orange, Tabby
```

this is my class: Dog

```
class Dog():

    myclass = "Dog"

    def __init__(self, name, dob, colour, breed):
        self.name = name
        self.dob = dob
        self.colour = colour
        self.breed = breed

    def printit(self):
        print('Class: ', self.myclass)
        print('Name: ', self.name)
        print('DOB: ', self.dob)
        print('Colour: ', self.colour)
        print('Breed: ', self.breed)
```

I tried to do this but I get an error "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 1)"

I googled this error but they are telling its about command line arguments(which I don't think this is the issue for me)

AM new to python, hope you can help

```
from animals import *

csv = []

fileobj = open("animals.csv", "r")

for line in fileobj:
    row = line.split(",")
    name, dob, colour, breed = [i.strip() for i in row]
    dog = Dog(name, dob, colour, breed)
    csv = csv + [ dog ]


fileobj.close()
```

Comment: I suspect the problem comes from `name, dob, colour, breed = [i.strip() for i in row]`. Try to print it and check the length is always equal to 4.

Comment: I tried running your code on my computer and it worked well